# RPM php_mbstring installation on RHEL 7.4 and PHP 7.3 | Call to undefined function mb_substr()

Tags: php, rpm, rhel7, php-7.3

May i know how to install php-mbstring. Here are my server version:

> OS:
> NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
> VERSION="7.4 (Maipo)"
>
> PHP:
>   PHP 7.3.4 (cli) (built: Apr  2 2019 13:48:50) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.3.4, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

I am restricted to connect to the internet. The only way to install php extensions is by downloading rpm. Here are the php extensions installed:

> php-gd-7.3.4-1.el7.remi.x86_64
>   
> php-7.3.4-1.el7.remi.x86_64
>   
> php-sqlsrv-5.6.1-2.el7.remi.7.3.x86_64
>   
> php-json-7.3.4-1.el7.remi.x86_64
>   
> php-pdo-7.3.4-1.el7.remi.x86_64
>   
> php-cli-7.3.4-1.el7.remi.x86_64
>   
> php-pdo-dblib-7.3.4-1.el7.remi.x86_64
>   
> php-xml-7.3.4-1.el7.remi.x86_64
>   
> php-common-7.3.4-1.el7.remi.x86_64
>   
> php-soap-7.3.4-1.el7.remi.x86_64
>   
> php-pecl-mcrypt-1.0.2-1.el7.remi.7.3.x86_64
>   
> php-pgsql-7.3.4-1.el7.remi.x86_64

Kindly point me to the right direction to get the installer for php-mbstring. My application is very dependent from this function. PHP 5.XX works perfectly fine but I need to update my PHP version.
Thank you

Comment: [This may help you.](https://linuxconfig.org/installation-of-missing-php-mbstring-on-rhel-7-linux)

Comment: Thank you @SeanBright . Already read the link before posting but my server restricts me from connecting to internet. Getting permission to connect to internet will be - I need to move mountains. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You obviously need the **php-mbstring** package.

Please be aware than

- RHEL **7.4** is outdated and unmaintained, current is **7.7**
- PHP **7.3.4** is outdated and unmaintained, affected by various security issues, including a critical one, current is **7.3.11**

BTW, you can download [php-mbstring-7.3.4-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm](http://rpms.remirepo.net/store/php/mbstring/7.3.4/php-mbstring-7.3.4-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm) from online archive.

Comment: Crazy amazing @Remi, as wooow, I really I cannot find that RPM - IT WORKED - Thank you so much

I am really bad searching REPOS, hope you can share any tips and links.

Comment: I am looking repos from here:
>https://rpms.remirepo.net/ 

But unfortunately cannot find php-mbstring-7.3.4-1.el7.remi.x83_64.rpm

Hope you can share what I am missing in using the remi repo site.

Comment: online archives are not really indexed nor designed for browsing, usually, URI given on request, see https://forum.remirepo.net/viewtopic.php?id=1966